# How to create double offset borders in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I create the double border in the attached image?

The issue I am having is the second border, I cannot get to sit behind the 1st border. I cannot do this with z-index as this then puts the whole second border behind the section background. I also need to consider that there will be a hover effect on the border.

```css
.style-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.style-wrapper article {
  flex: 1 0 26%;
  text-align: center;
}

.style-wrapper article .img-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.style-wrapper article .img-wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<section style="background:#e9e9e9">
  <div class="style-wrapper">
    <article>
      <a href="">
        <figure>
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img width="400" height="394" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Sculpture</h5>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </article>
    <article>
      <a href="">
        <figure>
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img width="400" height="394" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Sculpture</h5>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

`.style-wrapper` is the container for all the articles.

(The second border in this is black just for easy of developing this result)

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Is your values `width: 400` and `height:394` are fixed? Or It can be changed?

Comment: @Kenny Yes. But I have solved it with the double box shadow:box-shadow: 12px 12px 0 -6px white, 11px 11px 0 0px $greyMid;

Comment: I did solve it by `position:absolute` but people have closed this question, so can't answer now it here

Comment: @Kenny Is your solution substantively different to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979312/2985643) for the linked duplicate [Double box/border? Is this possible in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44979122/2985643) which also used `position: absolute;`?